# How do I hide the My Site Link in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I would just like to hide the link and keep the other links like Welcome *name* and My Links.  I just want to hide the My Site link, but I do not want to remove it from the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the link from your master page; it looks like this:-

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink1" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/>
<wssuc:Welcome id="explitLogout" runat="server"/>
```

it's the second link...

You might find this useful

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/BaseMasterPages.aspx

edit---
I should have added that you should not delete the link only comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

See [Disable MySite and MyLinks in Sharepoint (MOSS) 2007](http://geekswithblogs.net/RogueCoder/archive/2006/11/01/95766.aspx) by Michael Van Cleave.

Note: for all users you specify, this will remove My Links from all web sites of all web applications that use the Shared Service Provider.